# webbrowser midified HTML code c#

Tags: c#, html, browser

I have webBrowser component and I would like to save modified HTML code to file.

I don't know if you understood me but browser navigates to one page, receives HTML + JS and then JS modifies HTML code, now I need to save that modified HTML code.

I have tried to use DocumentText but form result I get it outputs original HTML code not HTML code modified by JS.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of developer plug-ins (Firebug or Firefox or Developer tools for IE or Chrome) will allow you to see the updated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outerHTML of an element you are interested in (i.e. BODY).

Look at methods of HTmlDocument like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx and HtmlElement - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.outerhtml.aspx

Comment: Could you post example as I cant find anything useful on MSDN

Comment: Updated with links to HtmlDocument and HtmlElement